# Excel adding cell content in another with HTML

Tags: html, excel

I need to make a rule to add content from one cell to another plus in Html tags
something like this:

http://www.jpeg.cz/images/2016/08/19/yMq2k.jpg

```
<div class="col-sm-4 extend-100">
    <a href="$A1" title="=$B1" >
        <span class="bigger-text"> =$B1</span>
        <span class="smaller-text"> =$C1</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest way is to break up your HTML into separate cells

D1

```
<div class="col-sm-4 extend-100"><a href="
```

E1

```
" title="
```

F1

```
" ><span class="bigger-text">
```

G1

```
</span><span class="smaller-text">
```

H1

```
</span></a></div>
```

Then in I1 concatenate

```
=Concatenate(D1,A1,E1,B1,F1,B1,G1,C1,H1)
```

Note that I've taken out the linebreaks as those will cause excel to add hidden quotation marks on the final cell to maintain them. You will probably need to clean your output anyway as quotation marks will probably be doubled. Also be careful on E1 and F1 that it maintains the quotation marks on the start of the string.